# Lightning component will create/insert record, but won't delete record

Tags: lightning-aura-components, delete

This is driving me insane - I'm sure I'm overlooking something simple here. I have simplified a component to isolate the issue, down to two basic operations: insert and delete. Insertion is working 100% perfectly fine. However, the delete method with nearly identical syntax will simply not work - the client-side method is called, because the `alert(recId)` is appearing and showing the correct Id value, and the window is reloading - **but the Apex method is never firing server-side, and the record is never deleted!**

I have also double checked that there is no trigger or other logic blocking the deletion of Notes in this org - if I delete the Note using Execute Anonymous, it works fine.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Client-side controller:

```
addNote : function(component, event, helper) {
    var action = component.get("c.createNote");
    var title = component.find("noteTitle").get("v.value");
    var body = component.find("noteBody").get("v.value");
    action.setParams({
        "title" : title,
        "body" : body
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
    window.location.reload();
},
deleteNote : function(component, event, helper) {
    var selectedItem = event.currentTarget;
    var recId = selectedItem.dataset.record;
    alert(recId); // this is correctly showing the right Salesforce Id
    var action = component.get("c.deleteNote");
    action.setParams({
        "recId" : recId
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
    window.location.reload();
}
```

Server-side controller:

```
public class SalesCallLogNoteController {

    @AuraEnabled
    public static Note createNote(String title, String body) {
        Note n = new Note();
        n.title = title;
        n.Body = body;
        n.ParentId = '0014B00000D8Bx7';
        insert n;
        return n;
    }

    @AuraEnabled
    public static Boolean deleteNote(Id recId) {
        Note n = [SELECT Id FROM Note WHERE Id = :recId];
        delete n;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: As an aside, you might have a race condition if you reload before you get a response back from the server. Use action.setCallback to reload after a successful action.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your server-side action and the client-side action have the same name: `deleteNote`. The client-side action is overwriting the client code for the server-side action, so it's calling the client-side `deleteNote` method over and over instead of making the server call.

If you rename one of them and update the calling code it should work.